# Safely share Redux state with 3rd party scripts

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Is there a good/bad practice to share the redux store state with 3rd party scripts?  Currently, we're using cookies to provide some state information to 3rd party scripts (non-sensitive state info).  However, we know the source of truth for the app is the redux store.  So to remain aligned with the core principles of redux, do you have any recommendations?

Here's an example.  So we have some legacy scripts that need to run in parallel with our react-redux application and they are currently reading some cookies before they execute.  For example, say we have a cookie called 'username' and it has a value of 'john'.  The 3rd party script reads that cookie and if the value is equal to 'john' it does something.

Internally, our react/redux application reads/sets this cookie using reducers/actions, but the third party script is not redux and just needs to know this 'name' value and also be notified if it changes.

I was thinking that we could create some react module that provides slices of the state tree and makes them available globally in the window.

It also seems that the redux-watch library could be useful: https://github.com/jprichardson/redux-watch

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a react module for this. Your 3rd-party scripts can simple subscribe to the store to get updates:

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  const username = usernameFromState(store.getState());
  // run the 3rd party code with the username
});
```

I don't see why this shouldn't be a problem. I think it is even okay for the 3rd party scripts to dispatch actions to the store, as you said the store "is the single source of truth of the application". And the 3rd party scripts are part of that application.